How do I rebase the remote branch onto the local branch when doing git pull?
I want any extra remote commits to be added after any commits done locally.
I have achieved this by doing
    git fetch origin
    git checkout -B newmain origin/main
    git rebase main
    git push --force-with-lease -u origin HEAD:main
    git switch -C main

But that is cumbersome (and probably buggy) so I'd like something simpler.

The simplest solution is to allow local commits to be rebased on top of remote with git pull --rebase origin main

Can you explain why you would want this? Your code shows clearly that it goes against the grain (having to push with force every time is a red flag).

This is a strange question. The wording is clear, but the end result is odd because you could restate your question like this: "I'm unhappy with a remote branch. How do I blow it away and replace it with something else?" The answer, of course, is: Fix up the branch locally to be how you want it, and then force push it. You've already done this. If this is a one off, what you did is fine and you don't need to get any better than that. If this is a regular occurrence, then the process for pushing commits to main is flawed, and it would be far better to fix that process, than your steps.

(continuing the previous comment...) I believe your ask is about preferring to complete merges into main in a specific order. Perhaps if you added branch protection with PRs/MRs, you'd then be able to make sure merges complete in the desired order.

To make things easier for future use sync_git.sh:
#!/bin/bash

# Function to display an error message and exit
die() {
  echo "[Error] $1" >&2
  exit 1
}

# Fetch the latest changes from the remote repository
git fetch origin || die "Failed to fetch from origin."

# Create or update a temporary branch to match the remote main branch
git checkout -B newmain origin/main || die "Failed to checkout or create 'newmain' branch."

# Rebase the local main branch onto the updated remote branch
git rebase main || die "Rebase failed. Resolve conflicts and try again."

# Push the updated branch to the remote repository
git push --force-with-lease -u origin HEAD:main || die "Failed to push changes to the remote repository."

# Switch back to the main branch, creating or updating it
git switch -C main || die "Failed to switch to 'main' branch."

# Success message
echo "[Success] The local and remote branches have been successfully synced."

